# Can I get to Sharm el Sheik from Hurghada?

Tags: transportation, ferries, egypt, sharm-el-sheikh

I heard that the regular ferry is not operating this route. Is that still true?

EgyptAir doesn't have direct flights (it goes thru Cairo and is very expensive). Is there any other way to do this route?

Answer (score 5):

I'm giving you my general opinion as an Egyptian not as an expert so don't take my answer for granted.

- Even if the regular ferry is not operating anymore, I think there will be other ferries there but not as regular. You have to be there and ask you might get lucky just plan for extra day.
- As far as I know the ferry used to be operated by Thomas Cook. You can contact them at this site http://www.thomascookegypt.com/home.aspx
- I don't recommend you to plan your own trip to Egypt. It is much better to go in travel package and be part of a group.

Enjoy your trip.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, There isn't a direct flight between these two cities, However in the case of ferries being suspended, there is a flight assigned daily to do so, it costs between $100 - $150 and took about 40min as described [here](http://www.alternativeegypt.com/Transport/Ferry-Hurghada-to-Sharm-El-Sheikh.html) in addition you can use the bus service as described in the same page:

> If you are time rich but cash poor consider taking a public bus or
>   service (shared) taxi between the two:
>
> ```
>  Route    Date        Departure Times
>  Hurghada - Sharm     Saturday    8am
>  Sharm - Hurgahada    Saturday    6pm
>  Hurghada - Sharm     Monday      4am
>  Sharm - Hurgahada    Monday      6pm
>  Hurghada - Sharm     Tuesday     8am
>  Sharm - Hurghada     Tuesday     6pm
>  Hurghada - Sharm     Thursday    8am
>  Sharm - Hurghada     Thursday    6pm
> ```

. And as I know the ferries are now operable, so you are preferred to use a one as ferries take only from 1.5 hours to 2.5 hours max to do the trip, in addition it is amazing to spend your travel time in a ferry in the red sea, and worth to mention that there are several trips during the day so you can choose what suites to the best according to the time.

And to know what are the available trips and their times times in addition how to reserve, have a look [here](http://www.ask-aladdin.com/ferries.html) and [here](http://www.egypt.travel/attractions/ferry-boat-ride-to-sharm-el-sheikh/):

> Timetable:
>
> ```
> DAY           DEP.TIME      ROUTE
> SUNDAY        08.00     HURGHADA/SHARM
> SUNDAY        18:00     SHARM/HURGHADA
> TUESDAY       08.00     HURGHADA/SHARM
> TUESDAY       18.00     SHARM/HURGHADA
> THURSDAY      08.00     HURGHADA/SHARM
> THURSDAY      18:00     SHARM/HURGHADA
> ```
>
> The trip takes around 2.30 hours each way
>
> Rates per person Prices for Egyptian and Foreign Residents (Egyptian
>   Pounds)
>
> One Way
>
> ```
> Adult: EGP 350
> Child: EGP 250
> ```
>
> Round-Trip
>
> ```
> Adult: EGP 630
> Child: EGP 450
> ​
> ```
>
> Rates per person Prices for non-Egyptians, Tourists, and Visitors (US
>   Dollars)
>
> One Way
>
> ```
> Adult: US$ 40
> Child: US$ 30
> ```
>
> Round-Trip
>
> ```
> Adult: US$ 70
> Child: US$ 50
> ​
> ```
>
> N.B : Children rates applied from 3 till 12 years old. Free ticket for
>   Children under 3 years old (Without seat)

At last, according to unstable situation in Egypt, ferries get being operable sometimes and some don't, so I mentioned all the available options for you, if ferries are there, go ahead and use it, if not, you have the option to use the bus or the direct flight from Egyptair.